# SAS - red x appears on program icon but still produces output and no error printed to log

Tags: sas

In SAS EG, I have a program with a macro. It is producing the outputs expected, but it completes as though it has an error, showing a red x on the program's icon and displaying the log rather than the outputs. However, there are no errors being printed to the log. This is causing issues when running the process flow as it shows the program as failing. The errors seem to come from two different areas, as when these are commented out, it works as expected:

```
%macro extract (start_date=, end_date=, product_type= );

data raw_&product_type.;
attrib
     one length=$14.
     two length=$1.
     three length = 8 format = date9.
     four length = $10.
     ;
run;
```

and

```
%if %sysevalf("&start_date."d) < %sysevalf("01jun2019"d) %then %do;
     ...
%end;
```

I suspect that in the second case, the error has to do with the loop as it's been causing me a lot of trouble. The &start_date variable is a global macro variable defined in a previous program that then feeds through. I'm not sure why the data attrib is causing this to happen as I've used a similar set up previously without issue.

Comment: What output thus `%put NOTE: start_date is &start_date;` produce?

Comment: Your `%macro extract(...);`-statement starts a macro definition and should go with a `%mend;`-statemend to end the definition. Is that there? _(And is is the macro also called in a `%extract(...)` ?)_

Comment: @DirkHorsten Yes to the mend statement and to the call. I've figured out what the issue was, answered below.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the issue.

Because I only posted a sample of my code, the problem wasn't even there to be found. In the data attrib section, I had a few numeric variables that had a dot where there shouldn't be, like so:

```
attrib
     one length=$14.
     two length=$1.
     three length = 8 format = date9.
     four length = $10.
     five length = 8.
     six length = 16.
     ;
run;
```

Those dots after variables five and six caused an error. Once removed, it was fixed.

For the second section, the error came in that &start_date was already defined to be "01Jan2020"d with the correct date formatting. Once the statement was changed to be:

```
%if %sysevalf(&start_date.) < %sysevalf("01jun2019"d) %then %do;
```

all worked correctly.

Comment: You still have some extra dots in that code.  The LENGTH of a variable is always an integer so there is no need to include a decimal point in the value.  You also do not need two calls to %SYSEVALF(). You can place the whole expression inside of one.  `%sysevalf(&start_date. < "01jun2019"d)`.